# Ramda - Forming a string based on array of word positions

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I saw this question and wondered how it'd be best to accomplish this using Ramda.

I'm new to the library so I thought it'd be an interesting learning exercise.

I have a working solution but it seems overly complicated and verbose. I'd be grateful for any suggestions on what other ways it would be possible to achieve this output using Ramda.

I'm aware that this doesn't need a library; as I say, I approached it as a learning exercise.

Here's what I have:

```js
const { addIndex, always, fromPairs, join, map, sort, toPairs, unnest } = R;

const song = {
  "99": [0, 7],
  "bottles": [1, 8],
  "of": [2, 9],
  "beer": [3, 10],
  "on": [4],
  "the": [5],
  "wall": [6]
};

const toSentence = join(' ');

const parsed = toSentence(
    map(
      ([_, word]) => word,
      sort(
        ([a, _], [b, __]) => a < b ? -1 : 1,
        unnest(
          map(
            ([word, indices]) => map(
              index => [index, word],
              indices,
            ),
            toPairs(song)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  
console.dir(parsed)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Reverse the order of the `sort` and the `map`, then the sort doesn't need to do \$n \cdot log(n)\$ array dereferences.  Your sort function is unstable and won't preserve the ordering of equal elements. It doesn't matter in this problem; when it does matter, it's a source of nasty, subtle bugs, so always be aware of when you're doing that.

Comment: @OhMyGoodness Thank you for your comment, which is very useful!

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question.

I found no easy Ramda functional way to solve this, but you could just use a forEach approach. I find it easier to read.

```
const {forEachObjIndexed, forEach} = R;

const song = {
  "99": [0, 7],
  "bottles": [1, 8],
  "of": [2, 9],
  "beer": [3, 10],
  "on": [4],
  "the": [5],
  "wall": [6]
};

let words = [];

forEachObjIndexed((indexes, word) => forEach(idx => words[idx] = word, indexes), song);

console.log(words.join(' '));
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach to the problem and I also find it easier to read than the code I had

Answer (score 1):

### Names

Variable names are very important,Try to keep the code understandable by defining named functions that relate to the abstract thing the do. (see example)

Same with the arguments. The names `indices`, and `index` are misleading. You are referring to the word position. Thus the names `positions` and `position` would be better suited. I would use `pos` rather than `position`

### Redundant code

- In the sorting compare function the two arguments `_`, and `__` are not not needed. The return can be any number value -10 and -1 are equivalent, so use the sorter for `a-b`.  `([a, _], [b, __]) => a < b ? -1 : 1,` becomes   `([a], [b]) => a - b,`
- The function extracting the word can be `pair => pair[1],` or `([, word]) => word,`  rather than `([_, word]) => word,`
- Why store the result in `parsed`. Just pass it on to the handling function. In this case the console.

### Scope clutter

Keep the Ramba functions associated with the object so you don't end up with name clashes, and it makes it clearer what is doing what. (see example)

### Example

```js
const lyrics = {"99": [0, 7],"bottles": [1, 8], "of": [2, 9], "beer": [3, 10], "on": [4], "the": [5], "wall": [6]};

const log = console.log;
const song = R.join(' ');
const position = ([a], [b]) => a - b;
const word = ([,word]) => word;
const swapPair = ([word, positions]) => R.map(pos=> [pos, word], positions);

log(
  song(
    R.map(
      word, R.sort(
        position, R.unnest(R.map(
          swapPair, R.toPairs(lyrics)
        ))
      )
    )
  )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```